# Fetching the domain name for a website from an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am using 
`var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ?     document.referrer:document.location;` to access the domain name of a website from within my iframe. Surprisingly this does the job! But will this work for all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent.location works on all browsers : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp